# How to find y of vertex of Parabola with y-intercept and x-intercepts

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics, conic-sections

I already know how to find the x of the vertex with this information but I do not know how to find the y of the vertex. How can I find the y? The x intercepts are (-1,0) (5,0) and the y intercept is (0,5) and the x of the vertex is 2.

Comment: You’re making a tacit assumption about the parabola’s orientation. There is an infinite number of parabolas that pass through these three points.

Comment: @amd Are you sure because I found out the parabola that passes through these points. And they aren't just any three points they include both x-intercepts.

Comment: Quite sure. Two of them are $(x-y)^2-4x-4y-5=0$ and $(2x+y)^2-16x-y-20=0$. Now, if you also assume that the parabola has a vertical axis, then you can use the result that the $x$-coordinate of the vertex is halfway between the $x$-intercepts, but without that assumption, you can’t. The vertices of the two parabolas above do not lie on the line $x=2$.

Comment: @amd Yes I'm assuming that the parabola has a vertical axis. How can the parabola have a negative x intercept and a positive x intercept with a horizontal axis?

Comment: It can’t, but that doesn’t mean that a vertical axis is the only other possibility. There are many other directions to choose from. The two parabolas that I gave as examples both pass through the three given points and neither one has a vertical axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the roots ($x$ intercepts), you can write the equation of the parabola as: $y = a(x+1)(x-5)$

When $x = 0$ (this is the $y$ intercept), $a(-5) = 5$, so $a = -1$.

So $y = -(x+1)(x-5)$

Set $x=2$ for the vertex (turning point) to find $y = 9$.

(From what you wrote, I assume you know how to find the $x$ coordinate of the vertex or turning point, but just for completeness, it is the arithmetic mean (average) of the two real roots, so here it is simply $\frac{-1+5}2 = 2$).

Comment: I only know standard form and general form for quadratic equations: y = ax^2 + bx + c & y = a(x-h)^2 + k. What is this form called?

Comment: I would call it the factorised form. It's the easiest form to see the real roots from. If you feel more comfortable with another form, just expand it. And I assume you know how to complete the square to get to that version too.

Comment: Yes I know how to complete the square and thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $x=-1$ and $x=5$ are zeros of your parabola, your parabola is $$y=a(x+1)(x-5)$$
Since your y-intercept is $(0,5)$ you get  $$5=a(1)(-5)$$ which implies $$a=-1$$

Thus your equation is $$y=-(x+1)(x-5)$$

You may write it in standard form $$y=-x^2+4x+5$$

Comment: I only know standard form and general form for quadratic equations: y = ax^2 + bx + c & y = a(x-h)^2 + k. What is this form called?

Comment: You may call it the factored  form. Any time you have a zero of a polynomial you have a factor of that polynomial.